# A pull-up resistor increases the low side of a signal, how can I counteract it?

Tags: resistors, signal, pullup

I have an ebike computer that has two inputs that accept square wave signals. The range is 0-5V. One of the inputs has no pull-up/down resistors on it. When I hook up a device producing signal, the signal is detected correctly. Both highs and lows are detected correctly. The other input has a built-in pull-up resistor. When I hook the same signal to it, only the high side is detected. Measuring the voltage of the low side, it's a bit higher than when hooked to the other input and I'm guessing it isn't crossing the low threshold the computer expects in order to register the low.

Am I right in thinking that the pull-up resistor is increasing the lows?

Is it possible to counteract the internal pull-up resistor by hooking a pull-down resistor to the input?

I'm a software guy with decent soldering skills and minimal knowledge in electronics so please answer like I'm not the brightest LED on the tree.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Attaching the schematic and relevant datasheets will help us give you a precise answer.

Comment: What are the measured voltages?

Comment: I wonder why no one suggested measuring _current_ in the low state. Because if it is too high you may have damaged input and then no tinkering with signal can help you

Comment: You should make sure if your signal source if working correctly.

Comment: @Maple I didn't measure current but I have a second computer of the exact same model and the behavior is identical on both. I also have two signal source devices and both produced the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it but I think that the pull-down resistor will worsen the other case.

Another solution can be to connect a "buffering" NPN transistor switch with "open collector" before the input. The input signal will be inverted but it probably does not matter to the software.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTP6dY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: STEP 1_1]

[image: STEP 1_2]

Comment: "the input signal will be inverted" well, it is not a solution then. and it is most definitely not a "buffer", it's an inverter. The real buffer may help, though. Something like [74LVC1G07](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G07.pdf). Assuming the problem is indeed in too high V_IL.

Comment: @Maple, OP is "a software guy" and it is no problem for their to invert the signal in a software way. This "buffer" is only a bare transistor.

Comment: Oops, sorry... I didn't realize it was a factory bike computer. Then two inverters can be cascaded :-)

Comment: OK, so I had a brainwave. I thought, wait a minute, I could use a transistor to translate the switching signal from the source to the computer but with voltages acceptable to the computer. Say 5V for high and 0V for low. But I don't know how I'd set a voltage threshold above which it'll switch on in order to match the source. But then I read this thread and looked briefly at what a buffer is, and it looks exactly like the device I'd need. How do buffers typically differentiate between high and low? Via threshold setting, observing rise/fall? Something else?

Comment: @Nicolay Doytchev, First of all, you need to know what the input signal source is.

Comment: Yes. I don't have the exact values with me at the moment but from memory I think I measured ~4.1V high and ~0.9-1.1V low. It's a square wave as. I'll remeasure it.

Comment: Reading the spec of the part you referenced above, I see Min for V_IH = 0.7V_CC and Max for V_IL = 0.3V_CC for V_CC around 5V. Are those values multiplication? Is 0.7V_CC = 0.7 x V_CC? If that's the case then the high threshold should be 3.5V and the low should be 1.5V. If this is correct then it should fit my input signal. Am I reading this right?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist thanks for the diagrams! The computer will unfortunately mind that it's inverted. It uses quadrature signal, so 2 square waves with a bit of phase shift to detect direction. If I flip one it probably won't work the same. Maybe flipping both will work but that might make it more complicated. I do get the point about decoupling the signal using a transistor though. I absolutely buy it. In fact I was thinking of doing it with the hammer I have - an Arduino with a few logical statements.  Now that I know there are parts that do this in a single package I think that'll be easy.

Comment: @Maple I answered my own question. I found [another spec sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g07.pdf) for a same-named buffer from TI where 0.7V_CC is denoted as 0.7 x V_CC. With that out of the way, what's "open drain"?

Re-measured the signal. When the source isn't connected to the computer it shows 4.5V high and 0.001V low. When connected to the computer, measuring between the input pin and ground I get 4.5V high and 1.1V low. If I connect to a secondary input that doesn't have a pull-up it measures 4.5V high and 0.45 low. The secondary input detects the signal correctly.

Comment: @NicolayDoytchev the "open drain" means the output of the chip already has the transistor connected exactly as in the schematics above. The open drain outputs are designed to work with pull-up, as they can only pull the line low. And non-inverting buffer means the chip also has inverter in front of that transistor, so what you get on the output is the same as comes to the input.

Comment: Does this mean that this part *won't* work with an input without a pull-up? Is there a part from this family that can both pull up and down? I probably won't need that as the second input which doesn't have a pull-up resistor works fine but I'm curious. I ordered the Nexperia part you mentioned.

Comment: @NicolayDoytchev Yes, it does. And any chip with push-pull output (like 74LVC1G16) can drive both up an down. Whether you can use it for both inputs depends on the input. The typical use of open drain (or open collector) is when same wire can be driven simultaneously by several sources, like in I2C bus. If they all can only pull low, then it is safe. If one pulls low while the other pulls high you have a short circuit. In any case, these buffers can only help if the problem is indeed too high VIL

Comment: Great. Thank you! I'll report back when I test the 74LVC1G07 part.

Comment: I just tried the 74LVC1G07 part inline and it works! Thanks you very much! This is the answer.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist if you add 74LVC1G07 as an alternative solution to your answer, it might help the next poor slob that doesn't know how to transistor. :)

Comment: @Nicolay Doytchev, Perhaps it is more correct for *Maple* to add it; I don't mind... or better describe it in their answer and you choose it.